# Problemas em chamar uma função de JavaScript num buttom em html!

Tags: javascript, html

Criei duas funções em js para dois botões no Html, uma lê o nome dos visitantes do site e o outro mostra o nome dos visitantes que já firam lidos, como segue abaixo:

```
var nomearray= [ ];

function nome(){

  var nome = prompt("Olá viajante, digite seu nome:")
  var cont = cont + 1;
  nomearray[0 + cont] = nome;  
}

function totalVisitantes(){

  for(var i=0; i<=cont;i++){
    alert(nomearray[i])
  }
}
```

**Obs**: eu declarei o array fora das funções para ser global e poder ser acessado na outra função.

No html, eu chamei elas assim:

```
< button onclick="nome()" >Qual seu nome?< /button >

< button onclick="totalVisitantes()">Visitantes< /button >
```

**Obs**: os button's estão no < head >.

Qual seria o motivo dos button's não conseguirem chamar as funções? A gradeço a ajuda de todos de antemão. Caso minha explicação tenha sido confusa, peço desculpas.

---

```
<html >
    <head >
        <title>Dark Site</title >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo1.css" >
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="script1.js"></script >

        <script language="javascript"> 
            function setCookie(nome, valor, dias){ 
            diasms = (new Date()) .getTime() + 1000 * 3600 * 24 * dias; 
            dias = new Date(diasms); 
            expires = dias.toGMTString(); 
            document.cookie = escape(nome) + "=" + escape(valor) + "; expires=" + expires; 
            } 
            </script >

    </head >
        <body >
                <button onclick="nome()">Qual seu nome? </button >

                <button onclick="totalVisitantes()">Visitantes</button >

            <h1><font color="white"><center>Historias Macabras</center ></font></h1>

            <script language="javascript" >
                if (!document.cookie){
                setCookie("cookie", "1", 365);
                document.write("<font face='verdana' size='1'>Visitas : 1</font>");
                } else {
                var cont = document.cookie;
                var dividindo = cont.split("=");
                //document.write(dividindo[1]);
                var numero = parseInt(dividindo[1]);
                var soma = numero + 1;
                document.write("<font face='verdana' size='1'>Visitas : " + soma + "</font>");
                setCookie("cookie", soma, 365);


                }
                </script> 

            <style type="text/css">
                img{border-radius: 20px;}
                </style>

            <h2><a  href="https://maringapost.com.br/ahduvido/10-historias-classicas-da-creepypasta/"><center><font color="red">A Estátua</font></center></a></h2>

            <table>
                <tr>

                <td><img src="1.jpg" width="300" height="250" alt="A Estátua" /></td>
                <td><font color="grey"><center></center>"texto"</center></font></td >

                </tr >
            </table>

            <h2><a  href="https://maringapost.com.br/ahduvido/10-historias-classicas-da-creepypasta/"><center><font color="red">A Carta</font></center></a></h2>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="2.jpg" width="300" height="250" alt="O Açogueiro"> </td>
                    <td><font color="grey"><center></center>"texto”</center></font></td>
                </tr >
            </table >

            <table >
                <tr>
                    <h2><a  href="https://maringapost.com.br/ahduvido/10-historias-classicas-da-creepypasta/"><center><font color="red">Espelhos</font></center></a></h2>
                    <td><img src="3.jpg" width="300" height="250" alt="O Açogueiro"></td>
                    <td><font color="grey"><center></center>"texto”</center></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table >
                <tr>
                    <h2><a  href="https://maringapost.com.br/ahduvido/10-historias-classicas-da-creepypasta/"><center><font color="red">O celular</font></center></a></h2>
                    <td><img src="4.jpg" width="300" height="250" alt="O Celular Novo"></td>
                    <td><font color="grey"><center></center>"texto".</center></font></td>
                </tr>
            </table >

            <center><table >
                <tr>
                    <td><embed src="song1.mp3" width="50" height="90" autostart="true"></td>
                        <td><h2><a href="beguin3.html">images</a>2</h2></td>
                        <td><h2><a href="file:///C:/Users/douglas/Desktop/DarkSite/beguin1.html">home</a></h2></td>

                     <a href="file:///C:/Users/douglas/Desktop/DarkSite/beguin2.html">1</a></h3></td>
                </tr>
            </table></center>
        </body>
</html>
```

Obs: ignore os textos por favor.

Comment: O problema era que o script do js não estava no html

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87138/discussion-on-question-by-douglas-nunes-problemas-em-chamar-uma-funcao-de-javasc) (cliquem no link caso queiram prosseguir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara como pode ver no meu exemplo, seu código está funcionando normalmente, apenas fiz algumas alterações em pontos que não estavam corretos:

> **1 -** Você tem que declarar a variável **cont** também fora da função `nome()`, pois está utilizando em **totalVisitantes()**.
>
> **2 -** Não é muito indicado usar nome de variável com o mesmo nome da função como você fez com **nome**.
>
> **3 -** Como **`nomearray`** é um **vetor**, você terá que utilizar o método **push()** para ir guardando os valores.

```js
var nomearray = [];
var cont = 0;

function nome() {

  var nomes = prompt("Olá viajante, digite seu nome:");
  nomearray.push(nomes);
  cont++;
  console.log(cont);
}

function totalVisitantes(){

  for(var i=0; i<cont ;i++){
    alert(nomearray[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="nome()">Qual seu nome? </button >

<button onclick="totalVisitantes()">Visitantes</button >
```